# How to define an NVARCHAR(MAX) field with sequelize?

Tags: sql-server, node.js, sequelize.js

Using node.js and sequelize vis-a-vis MSSQL, how do I define an NVARCHAR(MAX) field?

Comment: to convert a data item in MSSQL would be: convert(varchar(max),field) as field - using max is not great practice however as this is only available as text if used in associated MS products like access - I would limit the available chars to max 255 where possible

Comment: thanks, but I specifically need nvarchar(max) (for storing JSON)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

If you give the datatype as TEXT in Sequelize
It will automatically convert that field to `NVARCHAR(MAX`) for SQL Server database.

I could not find this in the documentation

But it is mentioned in [Sequelize github repository](https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize/blob/master/lib/dialects/mssql/data-types.js) from line 79 to 90.

Pasting here the code snippet:

```
    TEXT.prototype.toSql = function toSql() {
    // TEXT is deprecated in mssql and it would normally be saved as a non-unicode string.
    // Using unicode is just future proof
    if (this._length) {
      if (this._length.toLowerCase() === 'tiny') { // tiny = 2^8
        warn('MSSQL does not support TEXT with the `length` = `tiny` option. `NVARCHAR(256)` will be used instead.');
        return 'NVARCHAR(256)';
      }
      warn('MSSQL does not support TEXT with the `length` option. `NVARCHAR(MAX)` will be used instead.');
    }
    return 'NVARCHAR(MAX)';
  };
```

As you can see SQL Server does not support TEXT field so it will convert it to `NVARCHAR(MAX)`

Answer (score 0):

FOR MYSQL: `DataTypes.STRING(65535)`

postgres supports Upto 1G for BOTH TEXT AND VARCHAR.

Answer (score -1):

just use `Sequelize.STRING('MAX')` as type

Comment: Nope, not working:

`ERROR: syntax error at or near "MAX"`  ("sequelize": "4.41.1")